# XGBOOST ERROR for AUTOML: Cannot build an XGBoost model - no backend found

Tags: xgboost, h2o, automl

I am running h2o automl using anaconda env on a CentOS 7 Linux machine(CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)). I get this error for XGBoost model.

`Cannot build an XGBoost model - no backend found.`

According to the docs, XGBoost option should work on a CentOS machine. I am using the latest h2o 3.28.0.3(pip installed in my anaconda env).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of code?

Comment: `import h2o
h2o.init(
    max_mem_size = 20,
    port = 54321    )
h2o.estimators.xgboost.H2OXGBoostEstimator.available()`